# Disabled some Autorun-Programs now Windows start in startup repair

Tags: windows-7, boot, autorun, system-recovery

my Problem was:
Computer doesn't start in Normal Mode ->
solved this Issue by installing autoruns.exe(from MS) in Compatibility Mode and disabled some Programs.
Then the Computer start normal but very very slow.

my Problem now is:
I disabled **a few more** autorun Programs but now the computer **doesn't start anymore**.
Everytime the Computer comes up it crashes, and boots into MS **Recovery Mode**, **after loading a few drivers**.

What I've tried:
 - Recovery Mode cant repair the computer.
 - Windows DVD Upgrade function only works on running Windows.

Comment: What did you stop running? Did you stop any MS services?

Comment: It could be :/  
But I work now with MS-Autoruns.exe several years and never run into this Problem.

Comment: You might have just disabled a critical service, which is causing problems, try pressing F8 on boot and booting into safe mode. If you can do that just enable all the stuff you disabled.

Comment: I cant boot into any mode.  I tried all the options, always same Result -> Recovery Mode.

Comment: Boot into `Safe Mode` and enable those things you disabled.  This is the reason you don't screw around with what is autostarted unless your familar with what will happen if you disable it.

Comment: **I cant boot into any mode.** Including Safe Mode.  I think I disabled this unwittingly.  I work in this branch so I usually know what I do.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday evening I used *Autoruns* on my *Windows XP* to disable *all* the drivers highlighted yellow and marked *File not found*. This morning I came to work, turned on the PC, and got a *BSOD* with error `0x00000007`. Either *Autoruns* was wrong about those drivers or the antivirus prevented it from accessing them properly.

I fixed the problem by pressing *F8* at startup to enter *Safe mode menu* (not safe mode itself, which would *BSOD* as well) , and choosing to boot into the last configuration that worked.

Comment: I would not recommend to use Windows XP [10 years after extended end of life](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-xp). At least not in any scenario where the PC has access to the internet (or any other network). ;)

Comment: Yes, that is the general consensus, but in my personal opinion and practice, the fears are exagerrated and do not countervail the benefits of XP as I see them. There is still a bunch of well-maintainted software that supports XP, including antiviruses, and the [One Core API](https://github.com/Skulltrail192/One-Core-Api) layer to improve compability with modern software. I believe my answer applies to later Windowses as well.